# Joint distribution for simple mixture of discrete and continous

Tags: probability, statistics

This is a problem 4.31 b) in *Statistical Inference* by Casella and Berger:

let $X \sim Unif(0,1)$ and $Y \sim Binom(n, X)$. What is the joint distribution?

The answer can be found in solutions manual but I don't know how to arrive at it.

This is where I get:

this is mixture of discrete and continuous RVs so there is no well defined pdf. But the distribution will be determined if we can get $P(Y=y, X \leq x) = P(Y=y|X \leq x)P(X \leq x) $. Obviously $P(X \leq x) = x$. And here I've got stuck: not sure if this is legit:

$P(Y=y|X \leq x) = \binom{n}{y} \int_{0}^{x} t^{y}(1-t)^{n-y}dt $ ?

And even if it is, I don't know how to compute the integral.

Comment: For non-negative integers $a,b$ you can find $\displaystyle \int_0^1t^a(1-t)^b\,dt = \dfrac{a!\,b!}{(a+b+1)!} = \frac{1}{(a+b+1){a+b \choose a}}$ using integration by parts.  This is related to the Beta function

Comment: What you have is an [Incomplete Beta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function#Incomplete_beta_function).